# Rendering to movie: Under File format there are no options for h.264, Qicktime or MPEG

Tags: rendering, file-format

I just downloaded Blender, testing to render animation. But there seem to be something missing under Output > File format. Here is my version

[image: screendump from Blender]

Greatful for help...:-I!

Comment: Also check the [release notes for Blender 2.79](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/More_Features), they describe this change.